# Chroot within chroot

Tags: centos, chroot, cloud-hosting, centos5

I'm using Centos 5.2 and when I try to make a chroot jail using the script, I get:

Copying libraries for /usr/bin/scp.
    (0x00007fff17bfe000)
cp: cannot stat `(0x00007fff17bfe000)': No such file or directory
...

I am currently using on a rackspace cloud server so i suspect that these dependencies are outside of my own root.

Does anyone have a better idea for jailing the sftp server on a cloud server using Centos 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a better idea for jailing the sftp server on a cloud server using Centos 5.2?

Update to OpenSSH 4.9 or higher and use the builtin chroot-capabilities for the internal SFTP server. There are no official packages for CentOS, though, so you'd have to build it yourself or install it from a third-party repository.

See e. g. [OpenSSH SFTP chroot() with ChrootDirectory](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590).

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a better idea for
>   jailing the sftp server on a cloud
>   server using Centos 5.2?

Hi, yes use MySecureShell : http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net